# Ways to do RegEx matching for *|TAG_NAME|*

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have an edm template input/generated by a web frontend, and I have to replace all merge tags in the format `*|TAG_NAME|*` with its corresponding value.

I tried to use the below RegEx but it seems I got an error on the `|` characters.

```
^\*|[0-9A-Za-z]+|\*$
```

Below is a sample template (in json format):

```
"fields": [
  {
    "key": "member_id",
    "label": "Member ID",
    "value": "*|member_id|*"
  }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Depending on which language you are using, `|` might need to be backslash-escaped to be taken literally.  Which language are you using and what is the error message?

Comment: @tripleee i'm using javascript on nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

| is a special regex metacharacter (means OR), therefore you have to escape it with \

```
^\*\|[0-9A-Za-z]+\|\*$
```